# Drop down of Superfish Menu appear under Smart Slide Show in wordpress

Tags: php, slideshow, superfish

I spent almost my entire Saturday trying to solve this problem and have not had success. Firefox 
works well, but in IE8 and Chrome, the dropdown menu appears below the Smart Slide Show 
(Flash). Please could someone help me? 
the link to the page: http://www.institutoforlanini.com.br/novosite

This is the code of the index:

```
<?php get_header (); ?> 

<div id=conteiner> 
  <div id=content> 
    <div id="slider"> php echo do_shortcode ('[smart_slide_show ]');?> </ div> 
  </div> 
</div> <! - End of content div -> 

<?php get_sidebar ();?> 

<?php get_footer ();?>
```

Comment: It works fine for me in all three of these browsers. Are you sure you're not caching an older version of the page?

Answer (score 0):

I think I see it. The parameter wmode=opaque is not in the script section, only the noscript section.

```
<script language="javascript"> 
if (AC_FL_RunContent == 0) {
    alert("This page requires AC_RunActiveContent.js.");
} else {
        AC_FL_RunContent(
        'codebase', 'http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,19,0',
        'width', '610',
        'height', '300',
        'src', 'http://www.institutoforlanini.com.br/novosite/wp-content/plugins/smart-slide-show/slideshow',
        'quality', 'high',
        'pluginspage', 'http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer_cn',
        'flashvars','url=http://www.institutoforlanini.com.br/novosite/wp-content/plugins/smart-slide-show/data.xml&baseColor=0xFF0000',
        'id', 'AnimatedLines',
        'bgcolor', '#FFFFFF',
        'name', 'AnimatedLines',
        'allowFullScreen', 'false',
        'allowScriptAccess','sameDomain',
        'movie', 'http://www.institutoforlanini.com.br/novosite/wp-content/plugins/smart-slide-show/slideshow'
        ); //end AC code
}
```